# Is there an enum for the ContentType property on a HttpWebResponse ("text/plain", "application/octet-stream" etc.)?

Tags: content-type, mime-types, httpwebresponse

The closest thing I could find was `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames` but that doesn't seem to have everything (like json) since it seems to be more focused around email attachments.

Comment: Something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362140/asp-mvc-are-there-any-constants-for-the-default-content-types). People usually deal with it by creating constants as `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames` would never be an exhaustive/complete list.

Comment: Related post - [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/477816/465053)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An enum doesn't make much sense.  MIME types are open-ended.  That is, the list is not finite: new types are added from time to time.

See [RFC4288: Media Type Specifications and Registration Procedures](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4288.txt?number=4288)

Comment: It makes sense to me. Not as part of the .NET framework because that isn't updated frequently (nor should it be). But as a separate library that could be updated as frequently as new types are added (and users of the library cared). Time zones are open-ended too but that doesn't seem to obviate the utility of libraries based on [tz database](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Tz_database).

Comment: @KennyEvitt We keep an internal enum for common types we use a lot. Nothing wrong with that. Seems better than magic strings, right?

Comment: Hindsight is 20/20 but MIME types, like HTTP status codes, whilst not finite, are a sensible use for constants or enums. As per my answer, in 2022, Microsoft include MIME type string constants.

Answer (score 14):

In 2022, with .NET Core and .NET 5+, this is now available via `MediaTypeNames`. For example:

- `MediaTypeNames.Application.Json`
- `MediaTypeNames.Image.Png`
- `MediaTypeNames.Text.Html`

Microsoft documentation around MediaTypeNames, and each of Application, Image, Text.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames?view=net-6.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames.application?view=net-6.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames.image?view=net-6.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames?view=net-6.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames.text?view=net-6.0

**Update 2013**:
Further MIME types have been added in .NET 8, and are much more exaustive:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames?view=net-8.0

Comment: Some of these mediatypenames also exist in .net 4.6, but important ones like application/json are missing

Comment: This is good, but it looks like it is quite limited. I was looking for `text/csv` but it isn't supported.

Comment: @MichaelMurphy It appears support for `text/csv` has been added in .NET 8, alongside a bunch of others! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames.text.csv?view=net-8.0#system-net-mime-mediatypenames-text-csv

Comment: @richard_ob it's about time!

Comment: @Richard I think you mean Update 2023 (not 2013)! Also, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[IANA's database](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/) is most likely to be complete. Currently, they have the list available in CSV format at `https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application.csv`. I am assuming this is a stable URL whose content changes as updates are made. If you want to stay up to date, you'd need to put together a mechanism that is appropriate for your needs.

There is also the [mime.types](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?view=co) file that comes with Apache which seems to have been derived from the said list.

Comment: A flat list is already offered as CSV-file by the IANA's database website.

Comment: I parsed the listed on Wikipedia some years ago and generated C#, its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362140/asp-mvc-are-there-any-constants-for-the-default-content-types

Comment: Here a link to the IANA database with working .csv links: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

If like me you wanted to have no hard-coded string in your code you can use something like below

`httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);`

which is essentially
`httpHeaders.add("Content-Type","application/json");`

Answer (score 1):

For my own limited purposes, I have made a static class that is basically a copy of the included .NET `MediaTypeNames` class but includes the MIME types I require; .NET `MediaTypeNames` is missing values I need.

```cs
public static class MediaMimeTypes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies that the MediaMimeType is not interpreted.
    /// </summary>
    public const string Octet = "application/octet-stream";

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies that the MediaMimeType is in a Comma Separated Values (CSV) format.
    /// </summary>
    public const string Csv = "text/csv";
}
```