# Why cannot I send a post to my WebApi through AngularJS's POST？

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've sent "mytest.html" onto the IIS and this project is made up of WebApi+Angularjs, and I cannot get a right request to my webApi……I don't know why?

【Codes for HTML】

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://lib.sinaapp.com/js/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div ng-app="A" ng-controller="Test">
           <form method='post' name='myForm'>
               <table width="100%">
                  <tr>
                      <td>Name：</td>
                      <td><input type='text' ng-model='user.name' name='myname' required/>
                               <span style='color:red' ng-show='myForm.myname.$dirty && myForm.myname.$invalid'>Name cannot be empty!</span>
                      </td>
                 </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td>Gender:</td>
                      <td>
                        <div ng-repeat='s in sexs'>
                        <input type='radio' ng-model='user.sex' name='mysex' value='{{s}}'>
                        {{s}}
                        </div>
                      </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                       <td>Hobby:</td>
                       <td>
                       <select ng-model='user.love' name='selLove'>
                           <option ng-repeat='l in loves' value='{{l}}'>{{l}}</option>
                       </select>
                       <span style='color:red' ng-show='selChoice(myForm.selLove.$dirty);'>You cannot choose "Please choose"</span>
                        </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
             <input type ='submit' value='Submit' ng-click='isDisable();'/>
           </form>
      </div>

    <script>

         var app = angular.module('A',[],function($httpProvider){

            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
         });


         app.controller('Test',function($scope,$http){

           $scope.user = {};

           $scope.sexs = ['M','F'];
           $scope.loves = ['Please choose','Programming','Piano','Swimming'];

           $scope.user.sex = 'M';
           $scope.user.love = 'Please choose';

           $scope.selChoice= function(isDirty){
                var isFalse = (myForm.selLove.value == 'Please choose' && isDirty);
                $scope.myForm.selLove.$invalid = isFalse;
                $scope.myForm.$invalid |= isFalse;
                return isFalse;
           };

           $scope.isDisable = function(){

                $scope.selChoice(true);

                var requestData = $.param($scope.user);
                alert(requestData);

                if($scope.myForm.$invalid){
                    alert('Invalid form');
                }
                else{
                    $http({
                        method:'POST',
                        data: requestData,
                        url:'http://localhost:60031/api',
                        success: function (data){
                            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                        }
                    });
                }
           };
         });
    </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

【Codes for WebApi】

```
 namespace AngularJSDemo.Controllers
    {
        using Models;
        using System.Web.Http;

        public class DefaultController : ApiController
        {
            [HttpPost]
            public Person GetPerson([FromBody] Person p)
            {
                return p;
            }
        }
    }
```

【Codes for model】

```
 namespace AngularJSDemo.Models
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Sex { get; set; }
            public string Love { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

【Codes for Register】

```
namespace AngularJSDemo
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
    using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
    using System.Web.Http;

    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Formatters.Clear();

            var jsonFormatInstance = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
            jsonFormatInstance.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatInstance);

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional,controller="Default" }
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the error in the console of my google chrome is:

**angular.js:10695 POST http://localhost:60031/api 415 (Unsupported Media Type)**

---

I've also tried to use json, but no help :(

```
$http({
                    method:'POST',
                    data: {p:$scope.user},
                    url:'http://localhost:60031/api/Default',
                    success: function (data){
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
```

And my Content-Type is:

```
var app = angular.module('A',[],function($httpProvider){

                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
             });
```

---

Because I have different kinds of ports, so as to cross the domain, I also did this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Request-Methods" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660641/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-when-calling-web-api-2-endpoint

Comment: @Mikkel：Sorry it still has no help

Comment: It should be due to content type header not being set properly. How did you test that? Could you update the question?

Comment: There is no need to use jQuery to serialize the object. The AngularJS $http service uses a built-in serializer automatically. Serializing it with `$.param` is probably causing the 415 error.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen：I've registered for application/json or application/url-form……, but no help.

Comment: @georgeawg：I've upgraded my codes to another way as what you told me without any help futher……:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is wrong

the URL should be : http://localhost:60031/api/Default

```
$http({
                        method:'POST',
                        data: requestData,
                        url:'http://localhost:60031/api/Default',
                        success: function (data){
                            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                        }
                    });
```

Also, it is better to submit the data as JSON not form-urlencoded

Comment: No. Yours still cannot help me……and besides, I've set the default controller in the registration in C#. And I wonder to know why I should  change this to "application/json"? You see that I've marked my function's input parameter as [FromBody]——That comes from form instead of "json" formation. "JSON" is just what I'm writing for.

Comment: Sine you are building a REST service, it is common to share the data in JSON, not a FORM fields
Can you share the request body that is being sent to the service? 
For your try with json, it should be data:{p:$scope.user}

Comment: Well……it still has no help at all：（ And what do you mean by {p:……}）？

Comment: @DongWei I am trying to help you here, the {p:...} is the JSON object that will be sent to the web API, your action has a parameter of type `Person` which is called `p`, you need to send a JSON object that has the same name, this is how web API will understand to bind the request body to your action parameter.
Also, please inspect the request sent and share the data to know what is being sent to the server

Comment: I suspect whether there's something wrong with my "cross-domain"? I've updated my codes in web.config

Comment: It would have shown a different error if it was related to CORS, this error is related to unsupported media type format which was the form-urlencoded, now please let me know which error do you have after you set the content type to json

Comment: Your action is called GetPerson, but it is a post which is not recommended, web api can route the actions by convention, if it was a GET request and the controller name was Person, it would have worked, but now you have to include the action name in the URL, so the correct URL should be: `http://localhost:60031/api/Default/GetPerson`

Answer (score 0):

All in all, I think:

1) We really have to use the default and set the headers as "application/json" like this following:

```
$http({
                    method:'POST',
                    data: $scope.user,
                    url:'http://localhost:60031/api/Default',
                    headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
                }).success(function (data){
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    });
```

2) And the make our WebApi "CORS" (Cross-the-domain), **so that's the FINAL ANSWER.**

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api