# string value is Empty when using FromBody in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net core web api. below is my simple post function which is having a single string parameter. The problem is when I use [FromBody] the string stays null. I am using PostMan to test my service. I want raw data to pass from client to my controller. In Postman I am selecting body type RAW and 
I set the header Content-Type text/plain. The Raw Body contains Just "Hello World" string.

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("hosted-services/tokenize-card")]
        public IActionResult Test([FromRoute]decimal businessKey,[FromBody] string body)
        {
            var data = businessKey;
            return new JsonResult("Hello World");
        }
```

Comment: The content of your POST request must be formated with a registered content-type. If it's application/json the content must be ```"mystring"``` with the double quote

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: [Source](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api). When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. Only XML and JSON content-types are supported by default.

Comment: I think Kalten has identified the issue, try using "application/json" or "text/json" as the value for the "Content-Type" header in Postman

Comment: so should I make my raw data like {"body": "Hello World"}

Comment: Your parameter is a string, so your raw content must be a json string. "Hello World" **WITH** the **"**

Comment: Nice to know that FromBody only support XML and Json. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FromBody string parameter is giving null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853188/frombody-string-parameter-is-giving-null)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like [the doc](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) says :

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header
>   to select a formatter.

Only XML and JSON content-types are supported by default. So you need to use `application/xml`, `application/json` or register a custom `IInputFormatter`.

Next, you need to send a content that match the selected content-type.
For json, if the parameter is `int` send a number. If it's a class, send a json object. If it's a string, send a json string. Etc.

```
int => 14
string => "azerty"
class => { "propName" : "value" }
Array => []
... => ...
```

In your case you should send `application/json` content-type  and as content :

```
"Hello string"
```

And not just

```
Hello string
```

[Aspnet core json input formatter implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonInputFormatter.cs)

[Aspnet core xml input formatter implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml/XmlSerializerInputFormatter.cs)

[Example: Creating a CSV Media Formatter](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters)

Comment: For .net core 3.1 post(url, JSON.stringify(yourVariable)) worked like charm at the controller MyMethod([FromBody] string yourVariable)

Answer (score 0):

I did make it work by passing as row data in PostMan. Do not forget to add "="
sign as prefix in to the values.

```
 public string Post([FromBody]string value)
 {
     return value;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Please = did not work.. For .net core 3.1 post(url, JSON.stringify(yourVariable)) worked like charm at the controller MyMethod([FromBody] string yourVariable)

Answer (score 0):

Frombody means that get body directly.it is not necessary to use variable and value pairs.

For Example:

Your controller is like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetStringFromBody([FromBody] string token)
    {
    ...
    }
```

False:

[image: False]

True:

[image: True]