# How can I pass a string to a post request in Angular?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular4-httpclient

I have done some searching and nothing seems to help.

My angular looks like this with username being a string.

```
getUser(username = null) {

if (username == null) {
  username = this.cookie.getCookieValue("username");
}
console.log(JSON.stringify({ username: username }));
console.log("passing in "+ username);

return this.http.post<User>(this.userBackendUrl + "/user", username, httpOptions).pipe(map(user => {
  console.log("Successfully got the user!");
  console.log(user);
  return user;
}));}
```

Backend method looks like

```
public ActionResult GetUser(string username)
    {
```

I can hit my method but my username string in the backend is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how the string is sent with the request you have to do the following:

**Sent as a plain string**

If your `username` or string is sent as **plain string** in the request like the following:

```
"testuser"
```

Then you can add the `[FromBody]` attribute to a **`string`** parameter in the controller, like the following:

```
public ActionResult GetUser([FromBody] string username)
{
   //...
}
```

If your username or string is not sent as `"testuser"` pass the variable or string to the JSON.stringify method like this:

```
return this.http.post<User>(this.userBackendUrl + "/user", JSON.stringify(username), httpOptions) //...
```

**Sent as a JSON object**

If your username or string is sent as a **JSON object** in the request like the following:

```
{
   username: "testuser"
}
```

Then you need to create a seperate class (a DTO for example, `GetUserRequest`) tp bind to, which should look like this:

```
public class GetUserRequest
{
   public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Later you can bind the model (your sent JSON object) to this class, again with providing the `[FromBody]` attribute and a parameter with the created class as the data type, like the following:

```
public ActionResult GetUser([FromBody] GetUserRequest user)
{
   //...
}
```

---

#### Multiple parameters *without creating an extra class/DTO*

As Lionel asked here are two ways I know how you can bind to multiple parameters without creating an extra class or a DTO.

*Unfortunately, you can not bind the `[FromBody]` to multiple parameters to my knowledge.*

But there are the following two ways:

**Send data as form url encoded**

If you send the data form url encoded you can bind the data/parameters with the `[FromForm]` attribute like the following:

Send the data as form url encoded:

```
username=test&email=test%40gmail.com&created=2018-08-07T15%3A02%3A00.736Z
```

Bind data with `[FromForm]` attribute:

```
public ActionResult GetUser([FromForm] string username, [FromForm] string email, [FromForm] DateTime created)
{
   //...
}
```

**Send data as JSON object and bind with Newtonsoft**

Another way would be using the `JObject` of Newtonsoft. This way is a little less intuitive to my opinion.

You would send the data as a normal JSON object like the following:

```
{   
   "username": "test",  
   "email": "test@gmail.com",   
   "created": "2018-08-07T14:53:54.639Z"
}
```

And then you would bind the data to a single JObject with a `[FromBody]` attribute and then bind the data to seperate variables like the following:

```
public void GetUser([FromBody] JObject requestBody)
{
   string username = requestBody["username"].ToString();
   string email = requestBody["email"].ToString();
   DateTime created = requestBody["created"].ToObject<DateTime>();
}
```

Comment: That didn't work do I need to add something to my route? Because my route attribute looks like this [Route("user")] and attribute looks like this [HtttpPost]

Comment: No that should be correct as you said that you can hit the method. What type is the username variable in the angular code (the one you send on the post request)? Is it a plain string or a JSON object?

Comment: It's a plain string, here I will update my code on here

Comment: Are you using ASP .NET or ASP .NET Core?

Comment: I am using .netcore

Comment: I think you get null because your string is maybe sent differently as you think in the request. Review my updated answer and also try to check how the string is sent using the developer tools maybe

Comment: @Lionel check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559050/string-value-is-empty-when-using-frombody-in-asp-net-web-api/41559569#41559569). Try sending a hardcoded value with double quotes to see if it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks @adiii4 , just curious how would I be able to pass in more data in the future? like void getInfo(string name, string email) without having to create an object

Comment: @Lionel I updated my answer with two ways I know how you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

modify your c# method like below

```
    [Route("GetUser/{username}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetUser(string username)
    {
       //code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Send as form data in Angular:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("userName", userName);
return this.http.post<any>(url, formData);
```

And add `FromForm` in ASP.NET, with the same parameter name(userName):

```
public IActionResult GetUserName([FromForm] string userName) {
```