# Calling post services using axios or fetch

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a dotnet core and react application, in which I have this service :

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
        public string  UpdateUserLangage(string liste)
        {
            if(liste != null )
            {
                return liste;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            }
        }
```

I tried to call this service using axios and fetch library :

**axios**

```
axios.default.post('api/preference/UpdateUserLangage', "test"  )
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

**fetch**

```
fetch('api/preference/UpdateUserLangage', {
            method: 'post',
                body: JSON.stringify("test")
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

As a result, I get an error :

[image: error]

The parameter `liste` is always null so I get the error !

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Does it work if you include a leading `/`, i.e `'/api/preference/UpdateUserLangage'`? Have you gotten the request to work with an external http client like e.g. Postman?

Comment: @Tholle : it is the same result, the issue is the null value of the parameter

Comment: The question is duplicated: [FromBody string parameter is giving null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40853188/4752488)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to axios or javascript at all. Your request is coming back with a 500 error. My guess would be that `liste` is null, and it throws `ArgumentNullException`?

Comment: yep the parameter is always null and this is the problem. I don't know why!