# Request For Help In using POST in postman and Angular Controller

Tags: angular, postman

I am using Postman for the first time to POST to a server. I get an error `a non-descript body is required`.

What should I put in the body? I selected JSON and raw.
[image]

This is the Angular controller code:

```
namespace backend.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class QuestionsController : ControllerBase
{
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What do you want the value of `string value` to be?

Comment: I am following a tutorial.  RIght now, any valid value is fine.

Comment: Just saying, that is not an angular controller. That is a c# class.

Comment: This controller is the backend for an angular front end app

Answer (score 0):

A POST request contains a payload (data which we want to be saved via this POST request). In postman, we need to send that through the request body. Add the JSON/data (in the acceptable signature) to be saved through the request in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853188/frombody-string-parameter-is-giving-null/40853424)

The body is :

```
"{  \"key1\": \"value1\" }"
```