# The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to send data of object to my Web API. The API accepts a parameter of class, which properties are type of int and string.

This is my class:

```
public class deneme
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int sayi { get; set; }
   public int reqem { get; set; }
   public string yazi { get; set; }
}
```

This is my JSON object:

```
{
   "id":0,
   "sayi":"9",
   "reqem":8,
   "yazi":"sss"
}
```

I want the api read the property "sayi" as integer.
but because it cant, it gives the error:

```
The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.sayi
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: You can't assign a string value to an int variable, cast the string as int

Comment: It's needs to be `"sayi": 9` (no quotes), or you must bind it to a string instead of an int, and convert it later yourself. No other option.

Comment: before i updated from asp.net core 2.2 to 3.0 it worked when i type "9". after the update, it doesnt work.

Comment: this could also be the error message when the number value is higher or lower than ints range, could be you need to define it as long, float, double etc.. just fyi for others googling this

Comment: It is supported starting in .NET 5, please check an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67153702/3799228

Comment: Just take a look at the solution <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/74913526/13644168">here</a>.

Answer (score 118):

For Asp.Net Core 3.0, it uses `System.Text.Json` for serialization and deserialization.

For using old behavior, you could use Json.NET in an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project by referencing [Json.NET support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support).

Short Answer:

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` which is preview version.
2. Change to `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Question is, why couldn't Microsoft just use the most downloaded NuGet package...

Comment: It's not as efficient or performant. Newtonsoft is a great package as it covers a huge array of use-cases. With that large number of use-casts, comes performance overhead costs. Microsofts was very focused with theirs. It was performance driven for aspnetcore.

Comment: I just had to go this route to get my object to deserialize properly.  For some reason `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` doesn't show up in the package manager and had to manually install it with `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.0.0`.  It'll indicate the package can be updated to 3.1.0, but it requires net core 3.1, which is still in prerelease as of writing this comment.  Writing this in hopes it helps someone else who ran into this issue!

Comment: Thank you. I think this kind of error shouldn't happen ever in default setup, it is not normal to submit { num: 0.2 } to the server get error of this kind with default setup..

Answer (score 36):

Starting in .NET 5, there is an [option to deserialize numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling?view=net-5.0) that are represented as JSON strings instead of throwing an exception.

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
     NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString |
     JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString
};

// serialize
string denemeJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Deneme>(deneme, options);

// deserialize
Deneme denemeDeserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Deneme>(denemeJson, options);
```

Comment: The name JsonNumberHandling doesnt exist on the actual context

Comment: @JhonHernández Are you sure you're using .NET 5?

Comment: Upvoted. This is the answer for a .NET 5 project.

Comment: Can you use this setting or similar setting to store a float like 1800.0 to and int property?

Answer (score 29):

First you should create a `JsonConverter` for it:

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Buffers.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace sample_22_backend.Converters
{
    public class IntToStringConverter : JsonConverter<int>
    {
        public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
            {
                ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = reader.HasValueSequence ? reader.ValueSequence.ToArray() : reader.ValueSpan;
                if (Utf8Parser.TryParse(span, out int number, out int bytesConsumed) && span.Length == bytesConsumed)
                {
                    return number;
                }

                if (int.TryParse(reader.GetString(), out number))
                {
                    return number;
                }
            }

            return reader.GetInt32();
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it this way on your model's properties:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(IntToStringConverter))]
public int GenreId { set; get; }
```

Or you can add it globally:

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => 
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new IntToStringConverter()));
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be stringtointconvertor?

Comment: Is there any non custom way to do this yet. I would think they would fix this and allow people to pass integers without quotes. This breaks many existing APIs. I think this is the best answer as I feel using Newtonsoft isn't moving forward in the right direction

Comment: It's scheduled for the next version of the .NET: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30255

Comment: You can also pass this as a part of the JsonSerializerOptions when calling the Deserialize method as such: 

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                    Converters = { new API.Helpers.StringToGuidConverter() }
                };

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, options);

Answer (score 10):

In `.NET CORE 3.X` the serialize/deserialize process is done using `System.Text.Json` not `Newtonsoft Json`. Edward's answer did not work entirely for me:

1. Installing from Nuget Manager `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` won't make step 2 to compile.
2. Yes, add in Startup `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` - you will receive an error, `AddNewtonsoftJson()` not recognized.

At least this happened to me.

As a fix, uninstall what you've installed at step 1. In package manager console, run: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.0.0-preview8.19405.7` . This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Better parse the values to `Integer` and send data to Server Side application from your Client side application, This worked for me. **Happy Coding!!**

```
{
  "id":parseInt(0),
  "sayi":parseInt(9),
  "reqem":parseInt(8),
  "yazi":"sss"
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I thought I was already implementing the suggested answer because I had the following in my Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                {
                    opt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                    opt.JsonSerializerOptions.AllowTrailingCommas = true;
                    opt.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString |
                        JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString;                    
                    opt.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
                });
```

For some reason it is being ignored in my controller, I don't know why, I had to implement the suggested fix by HRKoder before it would work.

Answer (score 1):

in js model, make sure your values are formatted as parseFloat();

Answer (score 1):

There is an another way: just create a DTO with the type string for number types and  convert it into the controller or to the type that you need.

Answer (score -3):

May face this issue in .net core, try to use

1. parseFloat() or parseInt()
   OR
2. Using Custom Attribute

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class YOUR_CLASS
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   [JsonConverter(typeof(IntFromStringConverter))]
   public int Sayi { get; set; }
   public int Reqem { get; set; }
   public string Yazi { get; set; }
}

public class IntFromStringConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override int ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, int existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string stringValue = reader.Value.ToString();

        // Parse the string to int
        if (int.TryParse(stringValue, out int parsedInt))
        {
            return parsedInt;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Failed to convert string to int.");
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

OR

3.At JSON level require we can use "sayi": 9 as number.
instead of any changes on C#.

```
{
   "id": 0,
   "sayi": 9,
   "reqem": 8,
   "yazi": "sss"
}
```

OR

4. Using Dynamic object and TryParse

```
       // Deserialize JSON to dynamic object
        dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
        int sayi;
        if (jsonObj.sayi != null && int.TryParse(jsonObj.sayi.ToString(), out sayi))
        {
            // Parsing successful
        }
        else
        {
            sayi = 0; // handle null/assign default value
        }
```