# How do I set Json.NET as default serializer in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

Converting an ASP.NET core 2.1 web app to 3.1 and found out a few endpoints broken because the new Json serializer works differently than Json.NET which is default in core 2.1.

I don't want to fix all my model class and want to set Json.NET as the default serializer..how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refined my google search and it has been answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57652537/192727

I followed exactly what @Tao Zhou suggested and it did the trick.