# Integer serialization while migrating Asp.Net Core 2.2 App to 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I am migrating an Asp.Net Core 2.2 Web Api to 3.1

I noticed that now System.Int32 are now serialized into strings by System.Text.Json

Before (2.2):

```
{id: 1, ..}
```

After (3.1) :

```
{id: "1", ..}
```

**Edit**
id is an int property in C#

So the Js consuming the web api needs to be changed - pretty heavy migrations that I am not hurried to do.

I found options for :

1. [Keeping NewtonSoft Json.Net for serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57652537/192727)

   It is a solution. But I 'd like to keep up to date with the latest technologies !
2. [Providing a custom converter for integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57652537/192727)

   It doesn't seem to work in my case

Is there a way to tell the new Json Serializer in System.Text.Json to serialize integers as 42 not "42" ?

Comment: In my opinion you should examine your Startup class. I made project for .net core 3.1 with web api template and I receive from controller int values as int, not string.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the API and the model you are serializing? Is `id` actually `int32` or is it a string/object or some other type? Do you have some custom converter registered? `S.T.Json` outputs ints as numbers, not string.

Comment: Can't reproduce in a standalone console app, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/svwxd4.  Can you please share a [mcve]?  What is true is that, unlike Json.NET, `System.Text.Json` will not automatically deserialize a `string` to an `int`, but that's not the problem you are describing.

Comment: @ahsonkhan : just made an edit that my property is an int

Comment: @dbc : thanks for the work. I actually saw examples from Ms that Don't have my "bad behavior" - so I am still wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading advice from **Hostel** and checking from a new Web Api ASP.NET Core 3.1 app and seeing expected behavior, I compared my **Startup.cs** to the one of Visual Studio template app.

I just added in **Startup.ConfigureServices**

```
services.AddControllers();
```

Despite the lack of that missing service, the controllers "worked", but not as expected.

Maybe because of the presence of another extension method that added other services.

Thanks to all for your careful reading, remarks and questions