# Dropdown display value getting populated in the id property of the mode instead of actual id in Angular

Tags: angular

I have implemented a dropdown that is populating correctly in my angular application but when i try to submit my form , it is showing the display text in the model instead of the Id. What could be the problem
To my knowledge all i need is

```
[(ngModel)]="newJob.customerId
```

UI

```
<label for="customer">Customer</label>
  <select name="customer" required #customer="ngModel" ngModel placeholder="Please select"   [(ngModel)]="newJob.customerId">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected>Please select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let customer of customers"  >{{customer.name}} </option>
  </select>
  <small *ngIf="customer.invalid">Please select a customer</small>
```

Component

```
  public createJob(form: NgForm): void {
    if (form.invalid) {
      alert('form is not valid');
    } else {
      console.log(this.newJob);
      this.jobService.CreateJob(this.newJob).then(() => {
        this.jobService.GetJobs().subscribe(jobs => this.jobs = jobs);
      });
    }
  }
```

Model

```
export interface JobModel {
  jobId: number;
  engineer: string;
  customerId: number;
  customerName: string;
  when: Date;
}
```

Update

```
Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request","url":"http://localhost:63235/job","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:63235/job: 400 Bad Request","error":{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|9e7e208d-44c84ff36cde4107.","errors":{"$.customerId":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.customerId | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 50."]}}}
```

Comment: Can you please share your `customers` array?

Answer (score 0):

You need a value on each option inside of the select, otherwise the default is the display value.
Try this:

```
<option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.customerId">{{customer.name}} </option>
```

Comment: The object is containing the following value customerId: "customer.customerId"

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

> value
>
> The content of this attribute represents the value to be submitted with the form, should this option be selected. **If this attribute is**
> **omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option**
> **element.**

So, you must provide value for your `<option>` tags:

```
<option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.customerId">
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  {{customer.name}}
</option>
```

If you have scrict validation on your server-side where it's required  `newJob.customerId` to be a **number** then you should be using **ngValue** instead otherwise you will be getting it as a string:

```
<option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [ngValue]="customer.customerId">
```

Comment: I can see the proper value using your logic but get an error {"$.customerId":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.customerId | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 50."]}}}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57626878/the-json-value-could-not-be-converted-to-system-int32

Comment: @jacob , why do you say used wrong property {{customer.name}}. Customers object is what gets populated in the component to display in the dropdown.

Comment: newJob which is an object of JobModel needs to be poulated on the client UI and submitted

Comment: @Tom I didn't say that. The important thing in my answer was the `[value]="customer.customerId"`. It's actually the same as @yurzui's answer. You still want the customer name to be what is displayed in the drop down correct? That is what {{customer.name}} does.

Comment: @Tom I changed `customer.id` to `customer.customerId`

Comment: Yes Jacob, Sorry i misunderstood you.

Comment: @yurzui where does customer.customer.Id come from? I dont have any id of customer

Comment: @Tom I was a typo. Sorry

Comment: customerId: "2"
customerName: null
customerType: null
engineer: "Ashley"
jobId: null
when: "2020-08-07"

Comment: @yurzui. I was using customer.customerId itself

Comment: As you can see i am getting the id is what i mentioned. But when i submit the form , I am getting the error that in the post

Comment: Can you please update your post with the actual `body` you're sending to the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219383/discussion-between-tom-and-yurzui).