# 415 UnsupportedMediaType when trying to intercept a POST request

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, gzip, php-ziparchive

My feed provider send me a .gz file (zip file) by POST request to my server.

I'm trying to implement the .NET code which will intercept POST request and unzip the file to open the file inside.

I'm just trying to intercept the POST request and unzip the content doing this :

```
namespace app.Controllers
{
    [Route("")]
    public class FeedController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody] string content)
        {
            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

it returns 415 UnsupportedMediaType.

How to intercept POST request which is a ZIP File, and how to unzip it to return the file inside ?

thank you.

Edit :

```
[HttpPost]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public IActionResult Post(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file == null)
                return BadRequest();

            try
            {
                using (var zip = new ZipArchive(file.OpenReadStream()))
                {
                    // do stuff with the zip file
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: `[FromBody] string content` looks wrong to me: I don't think it'll be a string parameter. I'd guess you want an [HttpPostedFileBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfilebase?view=netframework-4.8) parameter, but I don't know the details.

Comment: I know it's wrong but how can I do knowing that the post request is a ZIP file ? how Can I decompress the zip file ?

Comment: I still think you want HttpPostedFileBase. If it's a .gz file you can extract it using [GzipStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.8). If it's a .zip file you can use [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.8), which will also work with streams, or [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/).

Comment: yes it's a .gz file. I edited my question. Can you please give me an implementation of GzipStream based on my code ? I'm a novice to treat such things. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A part of the problem is solved.

To read a .gz file sended by POST request you should do this :

```
[HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/gzip")]
        public IActionResult Post(IFormFile file)
        {

                WebClient Client = new WebClient();
                Client.DownloadFile("http://xxxxxx.com/feed.gz", "C:\\temp\\mygzipfile.gz");
                // do something with this file
            return Ok();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you missing the ContentType header? [Check out this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660641/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-when-calling-web-api-2-endpoint/42212196) for more detailed information.