# "application/json" constant in .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, content-type

I've just declared a constant for the "application/json" content type in one of my classes.

```
public const string JsonContentType = "application/json";
```

I'm not sure it is a good practice.

Does .NET framework have a predefined const for "application/json"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015892/is-there-an-enum-for-the-contenttype-property-on-a-httpwebresponse-text-plain

Comment: Related post - [ASP MVC - Are there any constants for the default content types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10362140/465053) & [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/477816/465053)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

See [Newer Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650792/270155).  This answer is now inaccurate.

While there are *some* MIME constants defined in MediaTypeNames (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362140/asp-mvc-are-there-any-constants-for-the-default-content-types)), there no constant for "application/json".

Putting additional content types in a shared const is probably best practice, better than defining them in string literals a million times throughout your code at least.

Plus it gives you the flexibility of using new/custom MIME types, which a specific .NET version might not have.

Comment: Glad that you mentioned about defining a public const best practice. That's the #cleanCode way of doing it rather than littering your code here and there.

Comment: The implied conclusion that it "enables" new/custom MIME types does not hold as having a *string constant* defined does not preclude additions to the open set (all possible strings) accepted. Since JSON/XML/HTML are so ubiquitous on the internet, having these standard (in one of the several) .NET Net/Web assemblies would be useful.. I wonder if .NET Core changes this answer?

Comment: Arg, or, with the related answer.. if only "application/json" was added..

Comment: .NET Core 2.1.0 has the `MediaTypeNames.Application.Json` defined :) See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/26701.

Answer (score 217):

In order to add an up-to-date answer: since dotnet core 2.1 `MediaTypeNames.Application.Json` has been defined.

See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/26701 for the changeset.

Comment: It looks like the `Json` constant isn't available in .NET Standard 2.0 though unfortunately.

Comment: Please mark this as the best answer or update the best answer.

Comment: same, this should be the proper correct answer

Answer (score 11):

There is now for Core 2.1, Core 2.2, Core 3.0, Core 3.1, 5, 6...

[System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames.application.json?view=net-6.0)