# Return "raw" json in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

The standard way AFAIK to return data in ASP.NET Core Web Api is by using `IActionResult` and providing e.g. an `OkObject` result. This works fine with objects, but what if I have obtained a JSON string somehow, and I just want to return that JSON back to the caller?

e.g.

```
public IActionResult GetSomeJSON()
{
    return Ok("{ \"name\":\"John\", \"age\":31, \"city\":\"New York\" }");
}
```

What ASP.NET Core does here is, it takes the JSON String, and wraps it into JSON again (e.g. it escapes the JSON)

Returning plain text with `[Produces("text/plain")]` does work by providing the "RAW" content, but it also sets the content-type of the response to PLAIN instead of JSON. We use `[Produces("application/json")]` on our Controllers.

How can I return the JSON that I have as a normal JSON content-type without it being escaped?

*Note: It doesn't matter how the JSON string was aquired, it could be from a 3rd party service, or there are some special serialization needs so that we want to do custom serialization instead of using the default JSON.NET serializer.*

Comment: json sent as the body or a param?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane JSON sent as the return value (body), so no params involved.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

And of course a few minutes after posting the question I stumble upon a solution :)

Just return `Content` with the content type `application/json`...

```
return Content("{ \"name\":\"John\", \"age\":31, \"city\":\"New York\" }", "application/json");
```

Comment: Better yet to return Json(your json goes here) as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: This was hugely helpful - thank you!  (If i return Json as per the above comment, then it returns it chunked which my client can't use.)  Your solution of returning Content with a specification of application/json is what solved my problem.

Comment: How do you do this for DotNetCore 2.1 ?  The "Content" method is not recognized - so I believe they've changed something since.

Comment: @MC9000 You need ASPNetCore 2.1.  NetCore2.1 is not enough. `Content` is a function of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`

Comment: You may consider using [`MediaTypeNames.Application.Json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650792) instead of `"application/json"` (for .NET Core 2.1+).

Answer (score 30):

In your action, replace `Ok()` with the `Content()` method, which lets you set the content (raw content), content type, and status code of your response: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.contentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: This is great. I have a feeling that this changed between ASP.NET Core 2 and ASP.NET Core 1.

Comment: another day of hair pulling here too. Would love to see a working solution for DNCore 2.1!

Comment: @MC9000 You need ASPNetCore 2.1.  NetCore2.1 is not enough. `Content` is a function of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me, where `Json()` did not:

```cs
return new JsonResult(json);
```

Comment: With the release of .NET Core 3.0 - as <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework> - we can now use JsonResult as a cleaner solution, and it does not require any Nuget packages as it is part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App framework