# How to return serialized JSON string, without further serialization from ASP.Net Core API

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-2.0

This question is similar to [Return "raw" json in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336680/return-raw-json-in-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api) but slightly more complicated.

I have a mixed content, some class like:

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimesStamp { get; set; }

    // this is actually JSON serialized data, 
    // which the function just passes through and doesn't need to understand
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Currently, a response would contain the `Id` and `TimeStamp` serialized correctly and `Data` would just be a string which would need to be deserialized one more time.

I'd instead want `Data` to be just pointing to the "Raw" json string, which I set it to, without further escaping it.

We don't make use of content negotiation, we only support JSON request and response, so this would be fine.

I know that I could deserialize the json string into a dynamic object and that would work, but why should the string be deserialized just to be serialized again?

So what I would want is something like

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimesStamp { get; set; }

    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

but **without** the need to spend unnecessary time to deserialize and again serialize the content of the json string.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. If it's a string, *you* know it's JSON, but the serializer has no way of knowing that. However, even if it could somehow determine that it's a JSON string, it would still need to internally deserialize it so it could work it into the rest of the object, before serializing the whole thing - effectively no different than doing it yourself.

Comment: Actually, I could store the string in a custom Type (JsonSting for instance) and then write some custom json.net filter or similar (I just looked into it briefly) so it's definitely possible. I just hoped there might be an easier way.

Comment: I meant it's not possible as a `string`. You are correct, but again, that converter would work by deserializing the string, so you're still deserializing either way.