# Wrong formatting with escape characters when calling System.IO.StreamReader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, streamreader

I'm fairly new to .NET, so this may be an obvious one, but I've been struggling with it for a couple hours now and it's utterly upsetting.

I'm trying to create a simple GET request that reads a JSON file and returns it, like so:

```
// GET: api/test
[HttpGet]
public string Get()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("data/test.json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return json;
    }
}
```

The `test.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

And `curl http://\[::\]:50001/api/test` returns:

```
"{\n    \"foo\": \"bar\"\n}"
```

Why is C# returning the string with the escape characters and enclosing quotes?

How should this code have been written for the JSON response to be properly formatted?

Any help appreciated, thank you

Comment: `\n` is a  new line, `\"` is a quotation `"` as we can see in the debugger

Comment: Hi Dmitry, it's not in the debugger. Those characters are in the string, being returned in the response

Comment: Thanks @kirk-larkin, I will look into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this ?

[Return "raw" json in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336680/return-raw-json-in-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api?rq=1)

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("data/test.json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return Content(json, "application/json");
    }
}
```

Edit:

As Kirk Larkin said, you can also do it like this:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    // File(string virtualPath, string contentType)
    // data/test.json needs to be in the wwwroot folder
    return File("data/test.json", "application/json");
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you very much.
Totally not obvious though

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever indeed, typo edited