# .NET Core 3.1 WebApi - Passthrough JSON response from another WebApi

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following setup:

- WebApi #1 - Returns JSON via an [OkResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1) class
- WebApi #2 - Returns JSON via an [OkResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1) class

WebApi #2 needs to call WebApi #1 and simply pass the JSON result back via its OkResult. The issue I have is if I do that, I end up with escaped JSON in the response:

```
"{\"id\":1,\"key\":\"value\",\"key\":\"value\",\"key\":\"value\",\"key\":\"value\"}"
```

What is the best way to just passthrough this return?

UPDATE:

Here is the code that makes the API call to WebApi #1:

```
public async Task<string> Get(string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            string responseBody = await _client.GetStringAsync(uri);
            return responseBody;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And here is the return in WebApi #2:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string data)
    {
        var uri = String.Format(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENDPOINT"), data);
        var result = await _client.Get(uri);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Comment: You have to provide more code on how you do your passthrough. Most likely you are doing one more JsonSerialization on a string that is already a json and that's why you get this. You just need to get a string and send it as a string further with appropriate headers

Comment: Added to the post. Thanks!

Comment: So in that code, the controller makes the "_client.Get(uri)' call which will return the "responseBody", which is the return from WebApi #1, a OkResult. So what I see happening is, the OkResult in the controller is serializing it again, which is resulting in the escaped JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
return Content(result, "application/json");
```

Comment: So the only issue there is, I really want to use the built in response types, like Ok, BadRequest, Problem, etc. I need to be able to send back a status code as well as the JSON.

Comment: OK, so if I new up a ContentResult class, I can set all that. I think that will do it for me. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, there is really som more details here that I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336680/return-raw-json-in-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api/48336960. Apparently these ordinary ones always assume that they are returning Json, and if they do return json input string has to be escaped or it won't be a valid json, it does not really know there is already json there