# Is there a constant for application/json-patch+json already defined in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, content-type, mime, json-patch

I am looking the following `Content-Type` in ASP.Net Core that is used when patching an entity:

```
application/json-patch+json
```

There is the class `MediaTypeNames` as answered in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655938/application-json-constant-in-net-framework) but it does not have the patch option.

Comment: It seems like there is no. You can just create your static class with extended list of media type names and add it there.